# Return hundreds of arrays efficiently?

Tags: solidity, contract-design

I have hundreds, or even thousands of arrays of integers that I'd like to return from a function.

I can't return one at a time, because the overhead of making a call to Etherum is too slow in javascript.

```
function getTimestampsFromArray(address[] contentProviders) public view returns (uint[][]) {
        uint[][] storage returnTimestamps;
        for(uint i = 0; i < contentProviders.length; i++) {
            returnTimestamps.push(addressToTimestamps[contentProviders[i]]);
        }
        return returnTimestamps;
    }
```

This is my current attempt. It compiles, but it seems that web3 doesn't recognize this type of function?

Does anyone have a way to do this efficiently?

Thanks!

Comment: When you say the overhead of making calls to Ethereum is too slow, what do you mean? Are you aware that calls are asynchronous, and you can [parallelize your multiple requests](https://shawntabrizi.com/crypto/graphing-eth-balance-history-of-an-ethereum-address-using-parallel-asynchronous-requests-in-web3-js/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This just isn't the way to look at a smart contract architecture. You need to separate concerns differently or you will create a very inefficient system.

This might be helpful: https://blog.b9lab.com/the-joy-of-minimalism-in-smart-contract-design-2303010c8b09

Your function seems to be trying to return a whole bunch of `addressToTimestamps`. Setting aside the operating cost of accumulating all this (might not be acceptable), it's wasteful to ask the blockchain to recite the data more than once. This is implicitly the case with a "return everything" pattern. It won't scale and it isn't necessary.

Proceed on the basis that software clients are responsible for syncing up. It should be possible to bootstrap an empty client from logs and maintain sync. Clients that need a high-performance datastore can use any caching strategy they like.

Software clients should generally offer users the means to independently confirm the truth of things *if they want to*. For example, the client might provide the `timeStamps` with the `contentProvider` and the `row` to a user can plainly see the truth of it by checking `getTimeStamp(address,row);`

Just a sketch for consideration:

```
pragma solidity 0.4.24;

contract TimeStamps {

    mapping(address => uint[]) public addressTimeStamps;
    mapping(address => bool) public isContentProvider;
    address[] public contentProviders;

    // software clients should listen to Logs to form their own off-chain searchable, sortable, filterable state

    event LogNewAddressTimeStamp(address sender, address contentProvider, uint timeStamp);

    function setTimeStamp(address contentProvider, uint timeStamp) public returns(bool success) {
        require(contentProvider != 0);
        require(timeStamp != 0);
        if(!isContentProvider[contentProvider]) {
            isContentProvider[contentProvider] = true;
            contentProviders.push(contentProvider);
        }
        addressTimeStamps[contentProvider].push(timeStamp);
        emit LogNewAddressTimeStamp(msg.sender, contentProvider, timeStamp);
        return true;
    }


    // this will throw an error if row is out of bounds, by design

    function getTimeStamp(address contentProvider, uint row) public view returns(uint timeStamp) {
        return(addressTimeStamps[contentProvider][row]);
    }

    // discoverable array lengths make the state completely discoverable;

    function getAddressTimeStampCount(address contentProvider) public view returns(uint count) {
        return addressTimeStamps[contentProvider].length;
    }

    function getContentProviderCount() public view returns(uint count) {
        return contentProviders.length;
    }

}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I suppose the limitation I didnt mention is that were trying to do this with a static webpage. So we would not have a server to provide logs...

Comment: Just to confirm what you're saying, how will the static web page discover the contract state, inspect transactions, and sign transactions?

Comment: It will use a hardcoded contract address in the javascript, and rely on metamask or equivalent to sign, but infura for reading and inspecting. Thanks!